# How to check Airplay device available in code

Tags: ios, iphone

I am using custom Airplay button for airplay. It's working fine

```
volumeView = [[MPVolumeView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
[volumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:NO];
for (UIButton *button in volumeView.subviews) {
    if ([button isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        airplayButton = button; // @property retain
        [airplayButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [airplayButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [airplayButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [airplayButton setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, iconSize, iconSize)];
        [airplayButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }
}
```

The issue is: Airplay device shows after apple tv gets disconnected.

I want to show alert on taping on the airplay button if there is no device available.

Is there any way to check airplay  device available ?